# Pointer in function argument seems not working

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, composition

I'm developing in C++. I have 2 objects : which are the StandaloneAgent and the ConfigManager.
I want from the Standalone Agent to reach a char * variable in the ConfigManager with a function .

```
int32_t StandaloneAgent::getConfigFile(char * file){
    int32_t code = mConfigMgr->getConfigFile(file);
    return code;
}

int32_t ConfigManager::getConfigFile(char * file){
    file = mConfigFile;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the ConfigManager objet is an attribute of the StandaloneAgent with the
`ConfigManager * mConfigMgr;` variable.
And the file I want to reach is located in the mConfigFile attribute of the ConfigManager.

The problem is :

While putting std::cout,
the mConfigFile in the is OK and
the file variable after the

```
file = mConfigFile;
```

is OK

But when I return in the getConfigFile() function of the standalone agent, the file variable is a null pointer and I don't know why.

Is there a C++ specification that I am missing ?

Comment: You don't _have_ a pointer reference in your function. A pointer reference would be `char*& file`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/96s1vW47K)

Comment: A pointer should work here no ?

Comment: If you change the pointer inside your function, that change is local to the function. The pointer you passed as an argument to the function remains unchanged - unless you take it by reference: `char*& file`

Comment: parameters are passed by value unless you pass by reference. Pointers arent special. `file = mConfigFile` modifies are variable local to `getConfigFile`

Comment: You pass a copy of a pointer to the function, then modify the copy. So it won't be visible outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to functions are either passed *by-value* or *by-reference*. Any variable passed *by-value* will be local to the function and any changes made to it is local to the function too. This means that when to assign a new value to the pointer (`file = mConfigFile`) you only change the pointer in the function. The pointer you passed as an argument is unaffected.

When taking arguments *by-reference*, the variable inside the function references the variable used to call the function. Any changes made to that variable will be directly made to the variable used in the call to the function.

In your case, that means that you need to change the `ConfigManager::getConfigFile` function:

```
int32_t ConfigManager::getConfigFile(char*& file){
    file = mConfigFile;  // the change is made to the variable used as an argument
    return 0;
}
```

If the pointer passed to `StandaloneAgent::getConfigFile` is also supposed to be changed (I assume it is), you need the same change there:

```
int32_t StandaloneAgent::getConfigFile(char*& file){
    int32_t code = mConfigMgr->getConfigFile(file);
    return code;
}
```

Comment: `StandaloneAgent::getConfigFile` also. But the point should get across.

Comment: @super Good point - better make that clear.